# summarise with dplyr outputting only one value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset like so:

```
> dput(data_melt)
structure(list(Compound = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Compd1", "Compound1"
), class = "factor"), Concentration = structure(c(5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c(".01uM", 
".1uM", "1.0uM", "10uM", "DMSO"), class = "factor"), Co.Agonist = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("High/High", 
"High/Low", "Low/High"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), class = "factor", .Label = c("Tau1", 
"Tau2", "Peak.Mean", "Area.Mean", "SS1.Mean")), value = c(1.38196479885153, 
1.14405508500302, 0.988961970528585, 1.44849126088629, 0.492462666110073, 
NA, 2.17712741416582, 1.67028746892543, 1.96489211952819, 1.2460774224718, 
NA, 0.485501088636007, 0.580120526488655, 0.530538989313623, 
0.884536240505712, 0.322958355856638, 0.740882962734369, 1.18088839355135, 
1.48745421674211, 1.16792544841743, 1.11656132754921, 1.14457816659658, 
0.0675070264176897, 0.176054869732887, 0.174862277854592, 0.200470189214318, 
0.187717771153427, 0.181176140081454, 0.117339926372974, 0.0941816692818621, 
0.156408537242293, 0.171156092362873, 0.0642141717879837, 0.107013341555486, 
0.0892122245482354, 0.151976744172333, 0.198474636073771, 0.188703600586299, 
0.10970902239241, 0.117358989261514, 0.100312892958432, 0.118208485589655, 
0.154895187369863, 0.101035151359696, -3926.26508451201, -696.475731092535, 
-4384.77847338655, -718.718487256701, -3164.8941685203, -818.006663108841, 
-4658.25223372398, -826.496302684798, -2416.89272653148, -2558.96929067338, 
-672.257745869921, -3996.85447223941, -706.5215296652, -4190.52281192937, 
-726.870892539311, -2852.22943401345, -831.88857277573, -4580.4780146496, 
-816.712564805672, -6189.10619924791, -2540.95473989213, -713.422629648631, 
7712.37025286162, 1906.38208801373, 7583.22998649368, 1879.68741296455, 
7424.47445663593, 2236.40541039894, 6178.69685860507, 2064.41869983299, 
5953.06397562968, 6373.90332689516, 1813.36551434687, 4585.08608292281, 
1524.44544360278, 4343.20955707026, 1547.28354007935, 4772.3012092321, 
1889.5819203618, 4251.33850498831, 1687.78145119834, 5978.28926211454, 
3879.07376129486, 1533.61842684178, -622.178041494169, -301.118488704851, 
-618.132026278872, -302.614140229218, -821.035687044046, -383.60893819189, 
-683.302506820162, -331.474546574133, -764.139865695781, -546.931098421476, 
-300.006976301825, -622.178041494169, -301.118488704851, -618.132026278872, 
-302.614140229218, -821.035687044046, -383.60893819189, -683.302506820162, 
-331.474546574133, -764.139865695781, -546.931098421476, -300.006976301825
)), .Names = c("Compound", "Concentration", "Co.Agonist", "variable", 
"value"), row.names = c(NA, -110L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000120788>)
>
```

My goal is to summarize the value column by the preceding columns (Compound name, Concentration, Co.Agonist, and variable.

I've tried this:

```
DatAgg = data_melt %>% group_by(Concentration,Co.Agonist,variable)%>%
  summarise(mean=mean(data_melt$value,na.rm=TRUE),sd=sd(data_melt$value))
```

but the output doesn't collapse the data.frame to only the unique combinations and it only returns one value for all the variables.

I'm looking to use this dplyr solution to get mean and sd for each unique combination of the group_by variables.

Comment: if you have plyr loaded you need to specify `dplyr::summarise()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax should be

```
 data_melt %>%
    group_by(Concentration,Co.Agonist,variable) %>% 
    summarise(Mean = mean(value, na.rm=TRUE),
              Sd = sd(value, na.rm=TRUE))
```

In the OP's code, it was taking the `mean` of the whole 'value' column (`mean(data_melt$value, na.rm=TRUE)`) after grouping by the variables.  So, there will be a single unique value.

As the 'data_melt' is a `data.table` object, data.table methods can be used as well.

```
 data_melt[, .(Mean = mean(value, na.rm=TRUE), Sd = sd(value, na.rm=TRUE)),
              by = .(Concentration, Co.Agonist, variable)]
```